How to use writable computed
In the following code am trying to change the ref value of the constant 'title' inside the computed setter, So I expect to change the value of 'title' when the computed start
<template>
<h3>Title = {{ title }}</h3>
<input v-model="firstName" type="text" placeholder="insert fname">
<input v-model="lastName" type="text" placeholder="insert last name">
<h3>---------------- Message ----------------------</h3>
<h4>{{ fullName}}</h4>
</template>


<script lang="ts" setup>
import {computed, ref} from 'vue'

const firstName=ref('')
const lastName = ref('')
const title = ref('')
const fullName = computed({
  get(){
    return firstName.value+' '+lastName.value
  }
  ,set(val){
    title.value=val+'NORMAL'
  }
  })


</script>


You would need to have a fullName.value = 'something' to trigger that computed setter. I think that a using a regular computed or maybe watch is more adequate. What are you trying to achieve in the end?

getters or setters should have no side effects.

Something like this is easier to understand and works well IMO.
<template>
  <h3>Title = {{ updatedTitle }}</h3>
  <input v-model="firstName" type="text" placeholder="insert fname">
  <input v-model="lastName" type="text" placeholder="insert last name">

  <h3>---------------- Message ----------------------</h3>
  
  <h4>{{ fullName}}</h4>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

const firstName=ref('')
const lastName = ref('')

const fullName = computed(() => firstName.value + ' ' + lastName.value)
const updatedTitle = computed(() => fullName.value + 'NORMAL')
</script>

Here's a playground.
